# How do I extend the authentication process in a blazor server side app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Cookie authentication in a blazor server side app.

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
```

What I am trying to do now is to change a static variable in a static class whenever the blazor server side app is validating the user authorization. Is there any easy way to do this?

EDIT:
Here is the implementation based on Plamen Yordanov's solution.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, configureOptions =>
                {
                    bool personalNummerConfigured = false;
                    configureOptions.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = (context) =>
                    {
                        if (!personalNummerConfigured)
                        {
                            var employeeClaim = context.Principal.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "EmployeeId").FirstOrDefault();
                            int.TryParse(employeeClaim.Value, out int personalNummer);
                            FbController.PersonalNummer = personalNummer;
                            Console.WriteLine($"PersonalNummer: {employeeClaim.Value}");
                            personalNummerConfigured = true;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });
```

Comment: Avoid `static` as much as you can. Especially for Authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to certain cookie authentication events and there is an OnSignedIn [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onsignedin?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Cookies_CookieAuthenticationEvents_OnSignedIn).

This event can be configured in your `Startup.cs` like this:

```
.AddCookie("AppCookie", configureOptions => {
     configureOptions.Events.OnSignedIn = (context) => 
         {
             //handler code
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         };
 });
```

You can check all the events you can subscribe to in the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've searched. But I have to use the OnValidatePrincipalEvent because this one is called when someone revisits the site. I add my solution to my question above.